# jQuery tooltip with links

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

How to make pop-up window with links to hover like a normal tooltip just a mouse could click on the links. How can this be done? mouseenter loses focus when navozhu on the link and the window closes

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery("span.mod_events_daylink_evn").live('mouseenter',function(){
        jQuery("span#"+cone).append(jQuery("div#"+newdiv));
            jQuery("div#"+newdiv).css("display","block"); 
}); 

jQuery("div.eeee").live('mouseout',function(){ 
     jQuery("div.eeee").css("display","none");
     });

});
```

Comment: Cab you create a jsFiddle of this?

Answer (score 0):

try qtip
a jquery plugin 
http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/

update by thomas guettler: updated URL, qtip2 instead of qtip.